# Which is the root folder of Kestrel in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

When creating an Angular SPA .NET Core app with VS 2017 and open an instance of IIS Express server as to host the app, what is the `root folder` of the above server? For example `localhost:57985`? How can I find that?

Comment: It depends on the template. It's usually `wwwroot` but could be anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this is stored in [Content Root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#content-root) and [Web Root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#web-root) settings of host.

Links will redirect you to the host setting doc section that share info about the default value and how to change it (via env variables, via code by using extension methods like `.UseContentRoot` and `.UseWebRoot` methods.

For example:

> **Web Root**
>   Sets the relative path to the app's static assets.
>   **Key**: webroot
>   **Type**: string
>   **Default**: If not specified, the default is "(Content Root)/wwwroot", if the path exists. If the path doesn't exist, then a no-op file provider is used.
>   **Set using**: [UseWebRoot](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/HostingAbstractionsWebHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L124-L132)
>   **Environment variable**: ASPNETCORE_WEBROOT

---

If the app template uses `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` method for host creation then the following is calling [internally](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L157):

```
.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
```